# What's the most secure way to grant a user permission to update in a multisite?

Tags: users, updates, permissions

I've created a multisite for a local charitable organization that contains five sub-clinics inside it. I have various plugins running (security, SEO, etc.) in the multisite activated "across the network".

I'd like to grant permissions for a user at this organization to check for updates every two days and apply any updates that come up. I don't necessarily want this user to have permissions to do anything else.

Is there a user level or a way to homebrew a user level that allows them to (a) log into the backend, (b) look for updates, and (c) update the multisite without giving them other authorial or editing permissions?

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to define a new role. An easy way to accomplish this is with the [role scoper  plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/role-scoper/). Otherwise you'll just have to [write that plugin yourself manually](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_role).

Here is a basic example pulled from the [Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_role#Example)

```
$result = add_role(
    'basic_contributor',
    __( 'Basic Contributor' ),
    array(
        'read'         => true,  // true allows this capability
        'edit_posts'   => true,
        'delete_posts' => false, // Use false to explicitly deny
    )
);
if ( null !== $result ) {
    echo 'Yay! New role created!';
}
else {
    echo 'Oh... the basic_contributor role already exists.';
}
```